# Packages wont install in docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install tesseract-ocr to docker from a Dockerfile. When I build the Dockerfile everything looks normal and i get no errors but when I run the container tesseract is not installed.

If I access the container using `sudo docker exec -t -i <container_id> /bin/bash` and manually install tesseract using `apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr-all` it installs and works perfectly. Why doesn't it work when I try to install it during the build process?

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr-all
RUN tesseract --version

FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR ocr
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why there's another `FROM python:3.7` within this Dockerfile? i guess this will change the base image thus your previous actions won't work

Comment: first of all, you have 2 `FROM` and this won't work without `COPY` the previous `FROM` commands. If you want to use the current structure, then you are looking at multi-stage builds. If not, using Python base image is also fine to install `tesseract-ocr` by `RUN apt-get -y install tesseract-ocr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are leveraging Docker [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) without realizing it.

When you put `FROM python:3.7`, you essentially throw away everything you have done above that, since you start a new stage.

The easiest solution I can see is to move

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr-all
RUN tesseract --version
```

into the `FROM python:3.7` stage, and remove the `FROM ubuntu:20.04` stage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch your user, since you likely don't have permission to run those commands. Something like this should work:

```
USER root
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr-all
USER <switch back to previous user>
```

You'll need to figure out what the default user is to switch back, which you can probably find in the Ubuntu docs or using `whoami`.